# How do I get RSYNC to work with a LaCie-2big-NAS?

Tags: permissions, rsync, nas, grsync

I am having a problem getting RSYNC to backup remotely to a LaCie-2big-NAS (internet connected HDD).  I have set all the permissions for the target directory to be "rwx" (read, write, executable) and if I ssh into the drive, I can rwx without issue.  However, I cannot use RSYNC to initiate a session.

I get the following error (from GRSYNC; same error from terminal):
** Launching RSYNC command:
rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete --modify-window=1 -l -s /home/ @XX.XX.XXX.XXX:/

sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/" failed: Read-only file system (30)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(657) [Receiver=3.1.2]
Rsync process exit status: 11

Comment: What is the "target directory" that you set up?  Can you do `ssh <lacie> touch /foo` (assuming it has a shell and `touch` is available)

Comment: Hi,  This is what I get when I try and touch the existing directory (that I can create, if I connect via ssh.  touch: /target_directory: Read-only file system